# RecyclerView autoscrolls when Picasso loads an image

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have pretty much standard fragment with standard recyclerview. It works fine, except two tiny little details:

1. When adapter is scrolled down a bit (so the top item on the screen isn't fully visible) and I call *notifyDataSetChanged* or *notifyItemRangeChanged* the adapter "jumps" a bit and autoscrolls so the top item (not top on the list, just top on the screen) is fully visible.
2. I'm scrolling down to the bottom of the list (let's say I have 2,5 items on the screen). Last item has missing thumbnail. Picasso finishes loading the thumbnail and same thing happen - adapter autoscrolls 0,5 height of the item so the first item is fully visible on screen. This is not happening if I hold the screen after scrolling.

I can deal with 1. by adding *recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);* but how to deal with 2? It's not happening when I remove the line with picasso so I guess it's at least partially responsible for this behaviour.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    MyAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        adapter = new MyAdapter((MyActivity)getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

recyclerview:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    //some constructor and holder class, nothing interesting is going on here

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ShelfViewHolder viewHolder = (ShelfViewHolder)holder;

        Item item = itemsToShow.get(position);
        Picasso.with(activity).load(item.getThumbnail()).into(viewHolder.thumbnail);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? Same issue

Comment: @AntonShkurenko Yes, but I have no idea how exactly this affects the behaviour of a ViewPager. I had a RelativeLayout. Inside this layout I had viewPager and included relativeLayout2. The viewPager had property: 'android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout2">'. Removing this line fixed the issue. Still, it makes no sense to me, but wrapping viewpager in linearLayout instead solved the issue.

Comment: But what about recyclerview?

Comment: Did you have recyclerview's height as "wrap_content"? Because I did, changing it to the "match_parent" did the job

Comment: I had a viewpager. Viewpager had an adapter which held 3 fragments. Each fragment had a recyclerview inside. I believe recyclerviews had height set to 'match_parent' and 'layout_above' set as mentioned before.